# Convergence of complex integrals: Necessary and Sufficient conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

Currently I am examining functions defined in the following way:

$F(z)=\int f(z,t) dt\ $where the integral is along some curve $\gamma\\$ not necessarily closed. I want to know necessary and sufficient for this integral to: exist, converge and be analytic in each case. I haven't been able to find much stuff online, if anyone could help me by providing some recommended texts or maybe explaining what the conditions are, with ideas for proof? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that, for each $z\in\mathbb C$, $f(t,z)$ is defined on some interval $(\alpha,\beta)$ (where $\alpha$ can be $-\infty$ and $\beta$ can be $+\infty$) and that:

1. the function $f\colon(\alpha,\beta)\times U\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is continuous;
2. for each $z\in U$, the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}U&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\z&\mapsto&f(t,z)\end{array}$$is integrable and the integral $\int_\alpha^\beta f(t,z)\,\mathrm dt$ converges uniformly on every compact subset of $U$.

Then the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&U&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\displaystyle\int_\alpha^\beta f(t,z)\,\mathrm dt\end{array}$$is analytic and$$f'(z)=\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(t,z)\,\mathrm dt.$$

The main theorem to prove this is a theorem due to Weierstrass: if $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of analytic function from $U$ into $\mathbb C$ which converges uniformly to $f\colon U\longrightarrow\mathbb C$, then $f$ is analytic and $(f_n')_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly on every compact of $U$ to $f'$.

Comment: Thank you very much,  I know this theorem, but how would it be applied here. My first though is dissecting the interval and the partial sums of its Riemann sum being the fn's?

Comment: Any ideas on how to prove this result?